# Can I create a new document (DocumentApp) and pass Body object as content?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In Google App Scripts, I wanted to be able to have a pre-built Body class. I wanted to do this, because that way I could have a build the body in a structured way from a JSON that I want to parse. Could I do this? I couldn't find any method that accepts an instance of Body class as the content. I am searching for something like `appendBody(Body content)`;

Comment: What would you pass the body object too?

Comment: I didn’t quite understand what you meant. But in case this is what you meant, I want to basically create a body object (which is like a structured way to represent the document) and then I want to pass that to something like setBody(Body content). What I want to accomplish is not use 10-20 appendParagraph and those individual methods and use a complete structured Body object instead.

Comment: There are no scripts in a new Document.  So  what would you pass it too?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make a copy of a Class Body object but it can't be added directly to Class Document document object.

Anyway, you could use a JSON to add all the body children that might be needed by your document (paragraph, list item, table)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#copy